Crossed random effects in Python with Statsmodels
Consider this toy dataset, simulated with crossed random effets, and then a mixed model fitted to it with lme4::lmer:
set.seed(123)

# Number of subjects and items
num_subjects <- 30
num_items <- 20

# Generate subject and item IDs
subject <- factor(rep(1:num_subjects, each=num_items))
item <- factor(rep(1:num_items, num_subjects))

# Generate fixed effect predictor
x <- rnorm(num_subjects * num_items, mean=0, sd=1)

# Generate random intercepts for subjects and items
subject_intercepts <- rnorm(num_subjects, mean=0, sd=2)
item_intercepts <- rnorm(num_items, mean=0, sd=1)

# Create a data frame to hold the data
dt <- data.frame(subject, item, x)

# Add random intercepts to the data frame
dt$subject_intercept <- subject_intercepts[dt$subject]
dt$item_intercept <- item_intercepts[dt$item]

# Generate residual error
residual_error <- rnorm(num_subjects * num_items, mean=0, sd=1)

# Generate response variable y
dt$y <- 5 + 3 * dt$x + dt$subject_intercept + dt$item_intercept + residual_error

# Fit the linear mixed-effects model
model <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|subject) + (1|item), data=dt)

# Summarize the model

summary(model)

dt$subject_intercept <- NULL
dt$item_intercept <- NULL

write.csv(dt, "crossed_re_01.csv")


The salient part of the summary output is:
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 4.818    2.195   
 item     (Intercept) 0.778    0.882   
 Residual             1.030    1.015   

Now we use the same data in Python to fit (what we hope will be) the same model using statsmodels:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model import MixedLM

data = pd.read_csv("crossed_re_01.csv")

# Fit the linear mixed-effects model with random intercepts for both subject and item
model = MixedLM.from_formula('y ~ x', data, re_formula='1', groups=data['subject'],
                             vc_formula={'item': '0 + C(item)'})
result = model.fit(reml=True, method='lbfgs')

# Print the summary of the model
print(result.summary())

# Extracting variance components
subject_var = result.cov_re.iloc[0, 0]  # Variance of subject random effect
item_var = result.vcomp[0]              # Variance of item random effect
residual_var = result.scale             # Residual variance

print("\nRandom Effects Variance Components:")
print(f"Subject Variance: {subject_var}")
print(f"Item Variance: {item_var}")

print("\nResidual Variance:")
print(f"Residual Variance: {residual_var}")

And the relevant output is:
---------------------------------------------------------
Intercept  4.526     0.403  11.225  0.000   3.736   5.316
x          2.943     0.058  50.820  0.000   2.829   3.056
Group Var  4.786                                         
item Var   0.443                                         
========================================================


Random Effects Variance Components:
Subject Variance: 4.786
Item Variance: 0.442

Residual Variance:
Residual Variance: 1.363

I was expecting fairly similar results for the variance components. The Subject random intercepts agree quite well, but the item and residual variance are markedly different.
My next step is going to be a Monte-Carlo simulation, but before cracking on with that I want to make sure that I'm doing the right things in Python ?

Could you compare your results agains observed variance. This is a better criteria for deciding how off is the model. print(subject_intercepts.var()) ---
print(item_intercepts.var()) --
print(residual_error.var()) --

Hi, @lynchian I have updated my answer with the solution. Please also check this issue thread on github for more details: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/9279#issuecomment-2169120409

@JohnnyCheesecutter thanks for the notification. I will take a look soon.

Ahh, this is interesting. I didn't know that statsmodels can fit models with crossed random effects. It's also very interesting that there might be some deep issue, or just a misunderstanding or typo. So I thought I would investigate.
It is not usually a good idea to make comparisons of different models just on the basis of a single result from each one. Just relying on a single comparison is bad because we might have just happened to simulate extreme values on that particular occasion. It is a good use case for Monte-Carlo simulation. So that's what I'm going to do here.
As per the OP we will simulate data in R, multiple (100) times, saving the relevant parts of the output (ie the random effects estimates) along with the simulated data itself in a csv file. So we will have 100 csv files that we then read into Python and repeat the process.
Here is the R code I used which I adapted from the OP:
R simulation and model fitting code
set.seed(15)

# Function to compute confidence intervals
CI_t <-  function (x, ci = 0.95)
{
  `%>%` <- magrittr::`%>%`
  Margin_Error <- qt(ci + (1 - ci)/2, df = length(x) - 1) * sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
  df_out <- data.frame(  sample_size=length(x), Mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x),
                         Margin_Error=Margin_Error,
                         'CI lower limit'=(mean(x) - Margin_Error),
                         'CI Upper limit'=(mean(x) + Margin_Error)) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = "Measurements", values_to ="values", 1:6 )
  
  return(df_out)
}

# Number of subjects and items
num_subjects <- 30
num_items <- 20

# Generate subject and item IDs
subject <- factor(rep(1:num_subjects, each=num_items))
item <- factor(rep(1:num_items, num_subjects))

# Generate fixed effect predictor
x <- rnorm(num_subjects * num_items, mean=0, sd=1)

nsim <-100  # number of simulations

df_res <- data.frame(run = numeric(), subject = numeric(), item = numeric(), residual = numeric())

for (i in 1:nsim){
  
  # Generate random intercepts for subjects and items
  subject_intercepts <- rnorm(num_subjects, mean=0, sd=2)
  item_intercepts <- rnorm(num_items, mean=0, sd=1)
  
  # Generate random intercepts for subjects and items
  subject_intercepts <- rnorm(num_subjects, mean=0, sd=2)
  item_intercepts <- rnorm(num_items, mean=0, sd=1)
  
  # Create a data frame to hold the data
  dt <- data.frame(subject, item, x)
  
  # Add random intercepts to the data frame
  dt$subject_intercept <- subject_intercepts[dt$subject]
  dt$item_intercept <- item_intercepts[dt$item]
  
  # Generate residual error
  residual_error <- rnorm(num_subjects * num_items, mean=0, sd=1)
  
  # Generate response variable y
  dt$y <- 5 + 3 * dt$x + dt$subject_intercept + dt$item_intercept + residual_error
  
  # Fit the linear mixed-effects model
  m0 <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|subject) + (1|item), data=dt)
  
  vc <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(m0))
  
  row_to_insert <- list(run = i, subject = vc$sdcor[1], item = vc$sdcor[2], residual = vc$sdcor[3])
  df_res <- rbind(df_res, row_to_insert)
  
  
  fn <- sprintf("crossed_re_%02d.csv", i)
  write.csv(dt, fn)
}

mean(df_res$subject)
mean(df_res$item)
mean(df_res$residual)

sd(df_res$subject)
sd(df_res$item)
sd(df_res$residual)

CI_t(df_res$subject)
CI_t(df_res$item)
CI_t(df_res$residual)


And this results in the following statistics that we will compare to what we obtain from Python's statsmodels next:
Subject:  1.99 (1.94, 2.05)  
Item:     0.99 (0.96, 1.02)  
Residual: 0.99 (0.99, 1.01)  

Python model fitting code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model import MixedLM
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import t


# SO_78525102.py

def CI_t(x, ci=0.95):
    n = len(x)
    mean_x = np.mean(x)
    sd_x = np.std(x, ddof=1)
    margin_error = t.ppf(ci + (1 - ci) / 2, df=n-1) * sd_x / np.sqrt(n)
    
    data = {
        'sample_size': [n],
        'Mean': [mean_x],
        'sd': [sd_x],
        'Margin_Error': [margin_error],
        'CI lower limit': [mean_x - margin_error],
        'CI Upper limit': [mean_x + margin_error]
    }
    
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(data).melt(var_name='Measurements', value_name='values')
    return df_out


# Initialize an empty list to store the results
results = []

# Loop through the filenames
for i in range(1, 99):
    filename = f"crossed_re_{i:02d}.csv"  # Generate the filename with leading zeros
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)  # Load the CSV file

    # Fit the linear mixed-effects model with random intercepts for both subject and item
    model = MixedLM.from_formula('y ~ x', data, re_formula='1', groups=data['subject'],
                                 vc_formula={'item': '0 + C(item)'})
    result = model.fit(reml=True, method='lbfgs')

    # Extracting variance components
    subject_var = result.cov_re.iloc[0, 0]  # SD of subject random effect
    item_var = result.vcomp[0]              # SD of item random effect
    residual_var = result.scale             # SD variance

    # Append the results to the list
    results.append({
    'run': i,
    'subject_sd': math.sqrt(subject_var),
    'item_sd': math.sqrt(item_var),
    'residual_sd': math.sqrt(residual_var)
    })

# Convert the list of results to a DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)

# Print the DataFrame
print(results_df)

# Extract the standard deviations of random effects into separate lists
subject_sd = [result['subject_sd'] for result in results]
item_sd = [result['item_sd'] for result in results]
residual_sd = [result['residual_sd'] for result in results]

# Calculate mean values
mean_subject_sd = np.mean(subject_sd)
mean_item_sd = np.mean(item_sd)
mean_residual_sd = np.mean(residual_sd)

print("\n")
print(f'Mean Subject SD: {mean_subject_sd}')
print(f'Mean Item SD: {mean_item_sd}')
print(f'Mean Residual SD: {mean_residual_sd}')

# Calculate standard deviations
sd_subject_sd = np.std(subject_sd)
sd_item_sd = np.std(item_sd)
sd_residual_sd = np.std(residual_sd)

print("\n")
print(f'SD Subject SD: {sd_subject_sd}')
print(f'SD Item SD: {sd_item_sd}')
print(f'SD Residual SD: {sd_residual_sd}')


# Calculate confidence intervals
CI_subject = CI_t(subject_sd)
CI_item = CI_t(item_sd)
CI_residual = CI_t(residual_sd)

print("\n")
print(f'Subject_CI: {CI_subject}')
print(f'Item CI: {CI_item}')
print(f'Residual CI: {CI_residual}')

# Plot histograms
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.hist(subject_sd, bins=30, alpha=0.7, color='blue')
plt.title('Subject SD Histogram')
plt.xlabel('Subject SD')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.hist(item_sd, bins=30, alpha=0.7, color='green')
plt.title('Item SD Histogram')
plt.xlabel('Item SD')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.hist(residual_sd, bins=30, alpha=0.7, color='red')
plt.title('Residual SD Histogram')
plt.xlabel('Residual SD')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

which results in these estimates and confidence intervals:
Subject:  1.98 (1.92, 2.03)  
Item:     0.80 (0.77, 0.82)  
Residual: 1.16 (1.14, 1.17)  

So, the true  parameters, that were used to simulate the data in R are:
Subject:  2.00   
Item:     1.00  
Residual: 1.00  

R managed to recover these very well (I am quite surprised that the confidence intervals are so tight. I will investigate this when I have more time).
On the other hand, statsmodels estimate for the item variation seems to be wrong, the upper bound of the confidence interval of 0.82 is distinctly lower than the lower bound of the confidence interval from R

Very cool observations Robert. Was wondering, did you create an issue on this on statsmodel git? I was thinking about creating it...

Just wondering, how did it happened that your reputation is equal to "1"?)

@JohnnyCheesecutter, account is "temporarily suspended for voting irregularities" ...

There may be some problems with how python interpret model formula. If you'll use the model definition like I did in the code below it will give exactly the same output as in R:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model import MixedLM


data = pd.read_csv("crossed_re_01.csv")

# define dummy group which is the same for all observations
data['school'] = 1

# Fit the linear mixed-effects model with random intercepts for both subject and item
model = MixedLM.from_formula('y ~ x + 1', data, 
                             groups='school',
                             vc_formula={'id1': "0 + C(item)",
                                         'id2': "0 + C(subject)"}
                                         )



result = model.fit(reml=True, method='lbfgs')

# Print the summary of the model
print(result.summary())


Model outputs:
         Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
=======================================================
Model:            MixedLM Dependent Variable: y        
No. Observations: 600     Method:             REML     
No. Groups:       1       Scale:              1.0302   
Min. group size:  600     Log-Likelihood:     -959.7656
Max. group size:  600     Converged:          Yes      
Mean group size:  600.0                                
-------------------------------------------------------
              Coef. Std.Err.   z    P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     4.524    0.449 10.086 0.000  3.645  5.404
x             3.001    0.045 67.427 0.000  2.913  3.088
id1 Var       0.778    0.264                           
id2 Var       4.818    1.293                           
=======================================================

Explanation
Basically it works the following way.
The R equation:
 y ~ x + (1|subject) + (1|item)
Has the following equivalent in Python:
# y ~ x + (1|subject) + (1|item)

data['school'] = 1 # same value for all observations
MixedLM.from_formula('y ~ x + 1', data, 
                     groups='school',
                     vc_formula={'id1': "0 + C(item)",
                                 'id2': "0 + C(subject)"}
              )

And the R equation:
y ~ x + (1 | subject) + (1 | interaction(da$item, da$subject))
Will be written in Python using this formula:
model = MixedLM.from_formula('y ~ x', 
                             data, 
                             re_formula='1',
                             groups=data['subject'],
                             vc_formula={'item': '0 + C(item)'})

PS:
This was explained by statsmodel maintainer:
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/9279
